# Makefile appending to variable for previous dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a command `foo` that accepts a list of parameters. I want to alter the parameters I pass to `foo` depending on the target I am building. I have tried appending to target-specific variables, but that doesn't quite do what I want...

So, for example take this Makefile (which doesn't work since foo is built by target1):

```
all: target1 target2

foo:
    echo foo $(foo_args)

target1: foo_args += abc
target1: foo
    echo Target1
target2: foo_args += def
target2: foo
    echo Target2

.PHONY: foo target1 target2
```

What happens:

```
> make all
foo abc
target1
target2

> make target1
foo abc
target1

> make target2
foo def
target2
```

What I want:

```
> make all
foo abc def
target1
target2

> make target1
foo abc
target1

> make target2
foo def
target2
```

Makefile syntax can be specific to GNU make. I'd also like to keep the parallelism so that target1 and target2 can be built in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalable variant of John's answer:

```
define add_target
foo_args_all += $2
foo_args_$(strip $1) := $2
$1: foo; @echo $$@
foo_targets += $1
endef

all:
$(eval $(call add_target, target1, abc))
$(eval $(call add_target, target2, def))

all: $(foo_targets)
foo:; @echo foo $(sort $(foreach g,$(or $(MAKECMDGOALS), all),$(foo_args_$g)))

.PHONY: all $(foo_targets)
```

Output:

```
$ make  -f sample.gmk
foo abc def
target1
target2

$ make  -f sample.gmk all
foo abc def
target1
target2

$ make  -f sample.gmk target1
foo abc
target1

$ make  -f sample.gmk target2
foo def
target2

$ make  -f sample.gmk target2 target1
foo abc def
target2
target1

$ make  -f sample.gmk target1 target2
foo abc def
target1
target2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing a number of details and there may be a better way of handing things (e.g. why are the targets `PHONY`? How does `foo` depend on `target1`?), a complete example that shows exactly how the files are generated will get you a better answer.

That said, something like the following should work in this case

```
.PHONY: all foo target1 target2

all: foo_args += abc def
all: target1 target2

target1: foo_args += abc
target1: foo
    @echo Target1

target2: foo_args += def
target2: foo
    @echo Target2

foo:
    @echo foo $(sort $(foo_args))
```

Comment: If you do `make target1 target2`, however, it will output one of `foo abc` or `foo def`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with making target-specific variables is that they are only available in the scope of that target.   In particular, if you were building a target with multiple dependencies, you would only go down one dependency at a time, and `foo_args` would only reflect the targets on the side of the tree you happen to be invoking `foo` from.

Another solution might be to use something like the following at the top of your makefile:

```
foo_args_target1 := abc
foo_args_target2 := def
foo_args_all := abc def
foo_args := $(sort $(foreach goal,$(MAKECMDGOALS),$(foo_args_$(goal))))
$(info foo_args is $(foo_args))
```

This has the advantage that `foo_args` is available globaly.  This still has a scalability issue though -- if you were to create a new target `all2 : target1 target2`, then you would have to add a `foo_args_all2 := ...` into the makefile (you couldn't automatically detect that `all2` was dependent on `target1` or `target2`, and update `foo_args` automatically).

Comment: This is a simpler version of what I have right now, and it does pretty much what I want. I was hoping for a more elegant and scalable solution, but if nobody gives a better answer I'll accept this answer in a couple of days.